Blurry/jagged text on PC after buying a new monitor
I just made an "upgrade" to a IPS monitor LG UltraGear 24” IPS, Full HD, 180Hz, 1ms.
The problem Im facing now is that everything looks harder to read.
ALSO, text based softwares are showing BAD Text, like shown in the images below.
First I thought it was a software-bug, but  when I saw the same problem in different softwares, I understand the problem IS with this monitor and windows10.
obs: I use this montior to work by connecting my notebook to this as my main screen.
I write code ALL DAY and this never happened once (LINUX OS).
So I'm pretty sure this problem is with This monitor + Windows10.
My Specs are:

Monitor LG UltraGear 24h 180hz
Nvidia 3060ti
32GB Ram
CPU: R5 5600x
Windows 10

Please, send help
Notion

VSCode

obs2: Using Notion on browser, doesn't produce the same bug (wtf)


You might need to adjust Windows ClearType,. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/cleartype/ , or disable it. 2. Try decreasing refresh rate to see if it helps. 180 Hz is fine for gaming, but can be a disadvantage, too. Try 60 Hz.


Hi, @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the reply! My older monitor was 144hz and worked just fine. Tried to decrease this new one to 144hz but the problem persist. I will try now the clearType thing.

Update: tried to decrease to 60Hz and disable ClearType = Didnt work.  Also tried to disable ClearType, didnt work neither. So sad

I've had a similar issue with the scale option in the monitor settings, I would try setting that to 100% so that 1px=1px and see if that makes any difference
